# Runtime error Unable to Cast Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Getting a runtime error while casting is done. How can it be solved?

```
public spc GetSc(int ID)
{
    var SC = from items in db.Stable where items.id== ID orderby items.id select items;
    SC.Cast<spc>();
    return (spc)SC; // This line throws the error
}
```

Error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Tool.Models.Transaction.spc]'
to type 'Tool.Models.Transaction.spc'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to return a single `spc` from an `IQueryable<spc>` (which can contain 0 to any `spc`'s) to a single entity.

Either call `.Single(OrDefault)()` or `.First(OrDefault)()` on SC.